# How to move an upload file within Google Drive to another folder programatically android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to move an uploaded a file to another folder in Google Drive while doing so I'm getting this error

> Drive item not found, or you are not authorized to access it

So I'm able to upload a file to root folder in Google Drive. Struggling to move the uploaded file to another folder within my Google Drive.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
   // Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), "0B47yVZw_BQ_JbkRpc2FrbmxUVUk").setResultCallback(idCallback);
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Result  :"+result.getStatus());
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        mFolderDriveId = result.getDriveId();
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient())
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                    return;
                }

                final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                      //  DriveFolder folder = mFolderDriveId.asDriveFolder();
                     //   DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), mFolderDriveId);

                        File file = new File(String.valueOf(imageUri));


                        // Read the contents and open its output stream for writing, then
                        // write a short message.

                        try
                        {
                            InputStream dbInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int length;
                            int counter = 0;
                            while((length = dbInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
                            {
                                ++counter;
                                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                            }

                            dbInputStream.close();
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                      MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("New file.mp3")
                                .setMimeType("audio/mp3")
                                .setStarred(true).build();
                        /*  folder.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);*/
                        DriveApi.DriveIdResult exFolderResult = Drive.DriveApi
                                .fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), "0B47yVZw_BQ_JbkRpc2FrbmxUVUk")
                                .await();

                        if (!exFolderResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
                            return;
                        }

                        DriveId driveId = exFolderResult.getDriveId();
                        //showMessage("driveid" + driveId.getResourceId());
                        final DriveFolder folder = driveId.asDriveFolder();


                        // create a file on root folder
                        folder.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);


                    }
                }.start();

            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                    return;
                }
                showMessage("Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId().getResourceId());
            }
        };

public void showMessage(String message) {
    //  Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "Messages of toast :"+message);
}

private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in
 * folder operations samples.
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B47yVZw_BQ_JbkRpc2FrbmxUVUk";

/**
 * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
 */
public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";

/**
 * Extra for account name.
 */
protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

/**
 * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
 */
protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

/**
 * Next available request code.
 */
protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

/**
 * Google API client.
 */
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();

}

/**
 * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
 * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
 * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
 * activities itself.
 */

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
               // .addScope(Drive.IZ)
               // .addScope(Drive.Ja)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
/**
 * Handles resolution callbacks.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

/**
 * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
 * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
 */


/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

/**
 * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
 * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
 * available.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

    if (!result.hasResolution()) {

        // show the localized error dialog.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }

    /**
     *  The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
     *  Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an  authorization
     *  dialog is displayed to the user.
     */

    try {

        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        Log.e(TAG,"Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }


}

/**
 * Shows a toast message.
 */


/**
 * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
 */
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: haha. Google drive = such a waste of time to do simple things. I'm not going over the code but you need to connect, query drive for folder to get the folder, upload file to folder if file doesn't exist and is not trashed! Yes, it gets worse. Checking if file exists is another query. Also the cache can be non-updated and there's a command to update it that can only be called once per minute max. Also files cant be overwritten so they need to be deleted first before writing again! And it still gets worse. Welcome to the time sink. see :https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/

Comment: @CmosBattery can you please send me some useful links

Comment: I did. See Google's example code in the previous comment.

Comment: @CmosBattery yahh tried that but it again saying  "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?"